# QTableView: Prevent a user from navigating away from a spesific row

Tags: pyqt, qtableview, qitemselectionmodel

I am having trouble preventing the user form changing the current selection, if the save action did not complete successfully. I can re-select a row using the QTableView's selection models' currentRowChanged signal but although the selection change, the blue selection indicator does not. See the image below.

*Example: In the image below the user attempted to add a new row nr 537. But the save action got an error and I don't want the user to navigate away from row 537 before the record is either deleted or edited and then saved*

Question: How do I move the blue line to the current selection? (the current selection is the last row) (The QTableView's Selection Behavior is set to select rows)

[image]

Here is the code I got so far:

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.__tableViewSelectionModel = self.__ui.tableView.selectionModel()
        self.__tableViewSelectionModel.currentRowChanged.connect(self.rowChanged)

    def rowChanged(self, current=None, previous=None):
        if save() == True:
            self.__ui.tableView.clearSelection()
            self.__ui.tableView.selectRow(previous.row())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this:

```
self.__ui.tableView.clearSelection()
self.__ui.tableView.selectRow(previous.row())
```

with this:

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0.00001, lambda: self.__ui.tableView.selectRow(previous.row()))
```

produced the desired outcome